# Usage in Activity separate class which creates Buttons with set onClickListeners on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, onclicklistener

I need to build app with 6 Activity screens and custom navigation tabs in a bar below them (all must have both icon and label). I made navigation buttons as separate layout and **include** them into bottom of each activity layout for not to rewrite the same code multiple times. Next I want to make them clickable in each activity and set listeners on them. At first I manually set listeners on them in **each** activity like:

```
val navTabA = findViewById<Button>(R.id.tab_A)
    navTabA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nav_button_active)
    navTabA.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, A_Activity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
... 5 more ...
```

It works well but the same code was written 36 times and it is not well. So idea was to make separate class which defines this buttons and sets listeners on them and each activity only imports them.

I tried to write something like this:

NavHelper:

```
package com.example.app

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button

class NavHelper
    : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val navTabA = findViewById<Button>(R.id.tab_A) 
        navTabA.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        when(v.id) {
            R.id.tab_A -> startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, A_Activity::class.java))
            }
        }

    }
```

Activity:

```
package com.example.app

import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView

class A_Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_A)
        setTitle(R.string.A_Activity_label)

        NavHelper()
}
```

But in this case buttons are not clickable (No effect on click and no click animation at all). What is the right way to use such class?

Comment: You should check fragments. Anyway, your A_activity should extend NavHelper.

Comment: Your activities need to extend NavHelper. `class A_Activity: NavHelper()`